How to get current page number and modify controls? React DocViewer
I'm using the DocViewer component from @cyntler/react-doc-viewer in my React application to display PDF documents. I'm facing two challenges:
Getting the Current Page Number: I need assistance in retrieving the current page number of the PDF document being displayed. The DocViewer component doesn't seem to provide a straightforward way to access this information. Can someone provide guidance on how to achieve this?
Modifying Controls: Additionally, I'm interested in customizing or modifying the controls provided by the DocViewer component.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'next/link';
import { CircleChevronLeft } from 'lucide-react';
import DocViewer, { DocViewerRenderers } from "@cyntler/react-doc-viewer";

const BookReader: React.FC = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const docs = [
        { uri: "https://assets.openstax.org/oscms-prodcms/media/documents/PrinciplesofFinance-WEB.pdf" }
    ];

    return (
        <>
            <div className='margin-top'>                
                <Link href="/library">
                    <CircleChevronLeft className='ml-7'/>
                </Link>
          
                <div className='mt-5 margin-bottom margin-display' style={{
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: 'white', 
                    overflowY: "auto",
                    minHeight: '90%',
                    maxHeight: "calc(100vh - 300px)",
                    width: "70%",
                    position: 'relative',
                    scrollbarWidth: "thin", 
                    scrollbarColor: "transparent transparent"
                }}>
                    {loading ? (
                        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', minHeight: '100vh' }}>
                            <img src="/kevin.gif" alt="Loading..." style={{ width: '200px', height: '150px' }} />
                        </div>
                    ) : ( 
                        <DocViewer         
                            documents={docs} 
                            pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers} 
                            config={{ header: { 
                                disableHeader: true,
                                disableFileName: true,
                            }}}
                        />           
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default BookReader;

